# Valgrind memcheck does not show source file

Tags: c++, arm, valgrind, embedded-linux

I'm investigating memory leak problems in a C++ application running on an embedded linux system (Yocto 1.5) with an ARM CPU.

Valgrind 3.8.1 is installed on the target.

The C++ program is compiled with gcc 4.8 with -g and -Og and is not stripped.

I've launched valgrind with the command below:

```
$ valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full /tmp/e3event-daemon -c /etc/e3event-daemon/config.json
```

Output of valgrind:

```
==7035== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==7035== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==7035== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==7035== Command: /tmp/e3event-daemon -c /etc/e3event-daemon/config.json
==7035== 
==7035== 
==7035== HEAP SUMMARY:
==7035==     in use at exit: 4 bytes in 1 blocks
==7035==   total heap usage: 421 allocs, 420 frees, 148,246 bytes allocated
==7035== 
==7035== 4 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==7035==    at 0x4834558: operator new(unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-arm-linux.so)
==7035== 
==7035== LEAK SUMMARY:
==7035==    definitely lost: 4 bytes in 1 blocks
==7035==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7035==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7035==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7035==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7035== 
==7035== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==7035== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

A memory leak is reported but a *by 0x8048691: main (in ...* line is missing. If I run the same program on my Ubuntu Linux machine (valgrind 3.10.1) I get this line which indicates where the problem is.

What should I do to get this *by 0x8048691: main (in ...* printed?

Comment: Valgrind 3.8.1 is several years old. I recommend that you try the latest, 3.12.

Comment: I am somehow stuck with that version since the product runs with Yocto 1.5 which comes with Valgrind 3.8.1.

Comment: OK, but I see at least 2 changes that affect ARM stack traces since 3.8.1 (see http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/dist.news.html)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out in the changelog. I'll try to backport a newer version of Valgrind.

Comment: This is still a general problem on many ARM platforms. I had the same issue, but upgrading Valgrind helped. Here are some instructions I followed: https://askubuntu.com/questions/604137/how-to-upgrade-to-valgrind-3-10-0-on-ubuntu-12-04

Answer (score 0):

Check if your vgpreload_memcheck-arm-linux.so is stripped from its debug info.

Comment: have you noticed that the question is 6 years old? :-)

Comment: yes But I figured out the answer now :-) thought would be helpful to someone who faces same problem.